# Creating a simple php page that allows the user to input characters to search for names

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to make a php page where we can input characters and select year of birth
After submitting it should show all the corresponding name but it doesn't work.
For example I input 'a' and the name containing 'a' having the same year as selected should appear.
This is my code:

In data.php I have like this

```
$person[0]=array('name'=>'Daniel','dateofbirth'=>2000);
$person[1]=array('name'=>'Gaetan','dateofbirth'=>1980);
```

My function.php

```
<?php 
function comparator($word,$dateofbirth) { 
    include("data.php");
    $p=1;
    for($i=0;$i<count($person);$i++) {
        $position=strpos(strtolower($person[$i]['name']),$word);
        if($position === false) {
            $p++;
        }
        else {
            if($dateofbirth==$person[$i]['dateofbirth']) {
                echo $person[$i]['name']  ;?><br /><?php
            }
        }
    }
    if($p==count($person)) {
        echo "No results found";
    }
} 
?>
```

And the index.php, I used get method

I think my function.php is the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What are the values of `$word` and `$dateofbirth`? Your code seems to work (except `$p==count($person)`) : see https://3v4l.org/vSHmu

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem - https://3v4l.org/oQ1BC - however I feel it's necessary to say that it's inefficient and in production data are never stored that way, you should store the details of people in a database and connect to it and perform an SQL query. This only answers the original question.

```
function findPeople($searchString, $YoB, $listOfPeople){
    $peopleFound = [];
    foreach($listOfPeople as $individual){
        if(strpos($individual['name'], $searchString) !== false && $individual['dateofbirth'] == $YoB){
            $peopleFound[] = $individual;
        }
    }
    
    return $peopleFound;
}

$listOfPeople = array();
$listOfPeople[0]=array('name'=>'Daniel','dateofbirth'=>2000);
$listOfPeople[1]=array('name'=>'Gaetan','dateofbirth'=>1980);

print_r(findPeople('a', 2000, $listOfPeople));
```